# Pod repo update doesn't work

Tags: ios, cocoapods

[!] CocoaPods was not able to update the `master` repo. If this is an unexpected issue and persists you can inspect it running `pod repo update --verbose`

Re-installing cocoapods doesn't fix the issue..

Verbose output:

```
/Users/wojtek/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:112:in `rescue in update_git_repo'
/Users/wojtek/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:106:in `update_git_repo'
/Users/wojtek/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:126:in `update_git_repo'
/Users/wojtek/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:334:in `update'
/Users/wojtek/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods-core/master_source.rb:15:in `update'
/Users/wojtek/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:88:in `block (2 levels) in update'
/Users/wojtek/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Users/wojtek/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:87:in `block in update'
/Users/wojtek/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:86:in `each'
/Users/wojtek/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:86:in `update'
/Users/wojtek/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/update.rb:23:in `run'
/Users/wojtek/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/claide-1.0.1/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Users/wojtek/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Users/wojtek/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/wojtek/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/Users/wojtek/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
Wojtek-Juramy-Macbook-Pro:433 wojtek$
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `pod install --repo-update` instead of using `pod repo update` seems to fix the issue