# pod update is resulting into error [fatal: unable to access]

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

After running pod update I am getting this error, I can only think of internet issue but my internet seems working fine. And another thing I noticed it is not happening every time, sometimes it just work fine with the same Pod file and some time result into mentioned error.

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git/': transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
[!] CocoaPods was not able to update the `master` repo. If this is an unexpected issue and persists you can inspect it running `pod repo update --verbose`
```

Comment: can you please share your pod file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pod repo update doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43719275/pod-repo-update-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

Repo updated but git not update. Check this link [click](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5077#issuecomment-200701010).

Comment: as I updated y Question, it is not happening every time, lets say every third time it results in to error, so I ma not sure if the link you shared will work.

Answer (score 0):

its mean the latest pod not updated yet on git , wait 2 or 3 days it will work until you can add .framework file in your project or can use one down version of pod like latest pod is 10.2 so you can use 10.1

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling CocoaPods:

> sudo gem install cocoapods

Once it will be finished then write below command:

> pod install

If pods were already installed. Otherwise, you will have to update all of them with

> pod update

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal go to your project i.e cd your_project_path hit enter and then run this command

> pod repo update --verbose

hope this will resolve your issue

for more info [check this link](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5077) it might help you